# Taking the KL divergence between a normal distribution and an empirical distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, kullback-leibler

If we have a multivariate Gaussian $q(\mathbf{a}) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu}, \Sigma) $ and an empirical distribution $P(\mathbf{a} ) = \sum_{k=1}^{K} p_k \ \delta(\mathbf{a} - \mathbf{a_k})$ and I want to calculate the KL divergence $D_{KL}(p || q)$, is this possible? It feels like maybe the following steps are valid, but I'm not 100% sure:

$$D_{KL}(p || q) = \int p(\mathbf{a}) \log \frac{p(\mathbf{a})}{q(\mathbf{a})} d \mathbf{a} $$

$$ = \sum_k p_k \int \delta(\mathbf{a} - \mathbf{a_k}) \log \frac{p(\mathbf{a})}{q(\mathbf{a})} d \mathbf{a}  $$

$$= \sum_k p_k \log \frac{p_k}{q(\mathbf{a_k})}$$

Is this right?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with it

Comment: To do this rigorously, you need both distributions to have densities that are absolutely continuous with respect to a third density.  In this case, that can be neither Lebesgue measure nor counting measure on the data.  Instead, *average those two reference densities* and use that for all integrals.  See the final definition in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition).